# SQL Query to Relational Algebra

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.aanbieding_id
FROM aankoop as a 
WHERE 2 <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM aankoop WHERE a.aanbieding_id = aankoop.aanbieding_id) 
ORDER BY aanbieding_id
```

And i wanne make a relational algebra scheme of this query, my solution is:

```
πid(F(count)(aanbieding_id)>=2(Aankoop))
```

But i'm pretty sure this is completely wrong, can someone help me please